# Compute $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left({1 \over n^2} + {2 \over n^2} + \cdots + {n - 1 \over n^2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left({1 \over n^2} + {2 \over n^2} + \cdots + {n - 1 \over n^2}\right)$$

I tried solving this by finding $d$ which is $a_2 - a_1 = d$, but I don't know how to continue with it because it goes to inifnity and $S_n$ i beilieve works only for an infinite set.

I also tried with sandwich, i mean $b_c \le a_n \le c_n$ but when I checked $b_n$ and $c_n$ limits they were not equal to one another so I couldn't find $a_n$ limit.

Would love to get some help, and sorry for my english, I study this on another language.

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{2}{n^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{n-1}{n^2}=\dfrac{1+2+\cdots+(n-1)}{n^2}$.

Comment: @Brody I knew that already.

Comment: Okay. How can you rewrite $1+2+\cdots+(n-1)$? What do you know about the limit of a rational function at infinity?

Comment: $(n-1)(n-2) / 2$ I guess? @Brody

Comment: @Dr.MV You're correct. My apologies. I'll delete and restate my comment.

Comment: @Brody No worry.  Just don't want confusion to ensue.

Comment: @Dr. MV Of course, thanks for pointing it out! So, we have $\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{2}{n^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{n-1}{n^2}=\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2n^2}=(n^2-n)/(2n^2).$ From here, you can break up the quotient and simplify. What do you get? Or, you can use the fact that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{a_k x^k+\cdots+a_0}{b_k x^k+\cdots+b_0}=a_k / b_k$.

Comment: @Brody You're welcome!  My pleasure.  ;-))  And  +1 for your comment.

Comment: @Brody thx brody

Comment: See also: [Evaluating the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n^2}+...+\frac{n-1}{n^2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1486104)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Comment: Still can't find how to get to $1 \over 2$ from here.

Comment: Can you find the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n(n-1)}{2n^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac12 \left(1-\frac1n\right)$?

Comment: Well yes. but it is the limit in the left side. how can you find in the right side now?

Comment: The limits are equal.  As $n$ grows to $\infty$, $1/n$ decreases to $0$.  The limit is, therefore, $1/2$.

Answer (score 5):

**Alternatively**, you may use a Riemann sum:
$$
\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{2}{n^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{n-1}{n^2}=\frac1{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k}{n} \to \int_0^1x\:dx=\color{red}{\frac12}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (\frac{1}{n^2} +\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{3}{n^2}+...+\frac{n-1}{n^2})= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}{2n^2}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{(1-\frac{1}{n})}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: same answer :-) I just saw your answer..I was busy with typing this I am new to here. it takes some time to type..